# SSL errors in Docker containers only (hosting with self-signed certificate)

Tags: ssl-certificate

I host various APIs on my company VPN using self-signed certificates. I recently tried to host a new API, and no matter what I did, I got SSL errors. Firefox reported PR_END_OF_FILE, while the Python `requests` library similarly complained about

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=7057): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:997)'))
```

I tried following multiple guides to replace the keys, and also tried switching from `gunicorn` to `uwsgi`. Nothing has made any difference. I have no problem using the same certificates to host outside of the Docker container.

Does anyone have an idea what could be behind this?

Comment: I also can use Docker on my Mac to host the container no problem. It's only my Ubuntu server that seems to have a problem. I tried upgrading Docker on the server to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was behind the problem: the permissions of the key files were set to be unreadable by the (non-root) primary user of my Docker container. Rebuilding the container to match my UID solved the problem.